# Why does my RawKernel reducer cause cudaErrorIllegalAddress?

Tags: python, cuda, cupy

My goal is to write a custom reduction kernel that returns both the argmax along each row as well as the difference between the max and submax (second-largest max). I am new to CUDA and I am working with cupy. As a first step, I tried to write my own `max(axis=1)` kernel. Sometimes it works, but for large matrices it will crash.

```
import cupy as cp
import numpy as np

maxval2d = cp.RawKernel(r'''
extern "C" __global__
#define THREADS_PER_BLOCK (32*32)
void my_maxval2d(unsigned int cols, int* src, int* dst) {
    __shared__ int block_data[THREADS_PER_BLOCK];

    unsigned int row = blockDim.y * blockIdx.y + threadIdx.y;
    unsigned int col = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    unsigned int threadId = threadIdx.y * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    unsigned int i = row * cols + col;
    block_data[threadId] = src[i]; 
    __syncthreads();

    // do reduction in shared mem
    for(unsigned int stride = blockDim.x/2; stride > 0; stride >>= 1) {
        if (threadIdx.x < stride) {
            int& a = block_data[threadId];
            const int& b = block_data[threadId + stride];
            if(b > a) {
                a = b;
            }
        }
        __syncthreads();
    }

    // write result for this block to global memory
    if (threadIdx.x == 0) {
        unsigned int left_col = row * cols + blockIdx.x;
        dst[left_col] = block_data[blockDim.x * threadIdx.y];
    }
}
''', 'my_maxval2d')

cols = 32*32
rows = 32

cp.random.seed(1)
src = cp.random.random((rows, cols))
src = (src*900 + 100).astype(cp.int32) # make integers from 100-999
dst = cp.zeros((rows, cols))
dst = dst.astype(cp.int32)

print('baseline:', src.max(axis=1)[0])

threads = 32

remaining = cols
counter = 0
while remaining > 1:
    block_dim = (remaining//threads, rows)
    thread_dim = (threads, rows)
    print(f'loop {counter}, remaining: {remaining}, block_dim: {block_dim}, thread_dim: {thread_dim}')
    maxval2d(block_dim, thread_dim, (cols, src, dst))
    remaining //= threads
    src, dst = dst, src
    counter += 1
print('custom:', dst[0,0])
```

The basic outline of the kernel was taken from the [CUDA Webinar slides](https://developer.download.nvidia.com/assets/cuda/files/reduction.pdf). I know that this code may have incorrect results for non-power-of-32 matrices, but for my (32, 1024) matrix I expect the results:

```
baseline: 996
loop 0, remaining: 1024, block_dim: (32, 32), thread_dim: (32, 32)
loop 1, remaining: 32, block_dim: (1, 32), thread_dim: (32, 32)
custom: 996
```

And indeed, when I set `cols = 32` and `print(dst[0,0])`, instead I get:

```
baseline: 994
loop 0, remaining: 32, block_dim: (1, 32), thread_dim: (32, 32)
custom: 994
```

But with a (32, 1024) matrix I get:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CUDARuntimeError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-858a0ab67cd5> in <module>()
     58     src, dst = dst, src
     59     counter += 1
---> 60 print('custom:', src[0,0])

cupy/core/core.pyx in cupy.core.core.ndarray.__str__()

cupy/core/core.pyx in cupy.core.core.ndarray.get()

cupy/cuda/memory.pyx in cupy.cuda.memory.MemoryPointer.copy_to_host()

cupy/cuda/runtime.pyx in cupy.cuda.runtime.memcpy()

cupy/cuda/runtime.pyx in cupy.cuda.runtime.check_status()

CUDARuntimeError: cudaErrorIllegalAddress: an illegal memory access was encountered
```

My intuition says that somewhere in the kernel it is stepping outside of bounds. But I can't understand where that might be. How can I fix this code to get the expected results?

Answer (score 3):

As I wrote this, I realized the mistake. If `total = (block_dim[0]*block_dim[1])*(thread_dim[0]*thread_dim[1])`, then `total` should be less than or equal to `src.size`. But I had 32 blocks in the y axis **and** 32 threads in the y axis, which created the out of bounds error. If one of `block_dim[1]` or `thread_dim[1]` are set to 1, then this works.